# Problem with nginx reverse proxy and docker. Only one proxy_path is working

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, reverse-proxy

I am completly lost.. So i have two proxy_paths in my nginx conf: '/' and '/api'. '/' redirects to my frontend and is working perfectly but the '/api' proxy path is not working at all. The proxy server is logging requests to '/api/' but not forwarding them to my actual api-server. I'm missing something. Is the '/' proxy_path some sort of catch all that overrides any other proxy paths? Any assistance would be invaluable! Thanks! Here are my configs:

nginx reverse proxy conf:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name proxy;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://frontend_prod:3000/;
    }

    location /api {
      proxy_pass http://api_prod:3333/;
    }
}
```

docker-compose:

```
version: '3.1'
services:

  proxy:
    build: ./proxy/
    ports:
      - '9000:80'
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - frontend_prod
      - api_prod

  frontend_prod:
    build: ./frontend/nginx/
    ports:
      - '3000'
    depends_on:
      - api_prod
    restart: always

  db:
    image: mariadb
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: hunter2

  api_prod:
    build: ./backend/api/
    command: npm run production
    ports:
      - '3333'
    depends_on:
      - db
```

Comment: Nignx configuration is ok. You say nginx is forwarding to your api server. What are the response codes? Are they 502, 503?

Comment: @RodrigoLoza sorry, i forgot to mention something. This is run on a vps that has a nginx server installed locally, that server is set up as a reverse proxy with ssl certificates. The idea being to have proxy routes to different projects in docker environments and provide https for all of them/their services. So the local nginx proxy has a proxy_pass on '/myproject' -> the nginx proxy in docker. That in turn reroutes requests to '/' to my frontend and requrests to '/api' to my api. Honestly i am completly lost, i have no clue where to even send my requests. :) I did get the docker proxy to...

Comment: forward my requests to the api - however the api now crashes on every request with RangeError [ERR_HTTP_INVALID_STATUS_CODE]: Invalid status code: undefined

Comment: @RodrigoLoza Never mind, turns out i messed up my error handler in express. Api is working fine, however the database is not. :) Thank you for trying to help!